# AOSP error - FAILED: /bin/bash -c "prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++

Tags: android-source

[  2% 247/11700] target SharedLib: lib...libart_intermediates/LINKED/libart.so)
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++ -nostdlib -Wl,-soname,libart.so -Wl,--gc-sections -shared  -Lout/target/product/generic/obj/lib out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtbegin_so.o   out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libart_intermediates/interpreter/mterp/out/mterp_arm.o
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libart_intermediates/type_lookup_table.o: file is empty
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libart_intermediates/verifier/instruction_flags.o: file is empty
art/runtime/base/scoped_flock.cc:37: error: undefined reference to 'art::OS::OpenFileWithFlags(char const*, int)'
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:3240: error: undefined reference to 'art::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, art::Primitive::Type const&)'
art/runtime/check_jni.cc:3056: error: undefined reference to 'art::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, 
art/runtime/class_linker.cc:2166: error: undefined reference to 'art::ObjectLock::ObjectLock(art::Thread*, art::Handle)'
art/runtime/class_linker.cc:2169: error: undefined reference to 'art::ObjectLock::WaitIgnoringInterrupts()'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[  2% 247/11700] Building with Jack: o...t_intermediates/with-local/classes.dex
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:148: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1

make failed to build some targets (06:55 (mm:ss))

**Getting this error when i run make -j16
Help me what to do !**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some of your object files have been corrupted. I suggest you either clean the dir `out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libart_intermediates` or/and clean ccache `ccache -C`

Answer (score 0):

First advice is not to build with `make -j16` as it takes too much ram.
For example compiling on 8 cores needs 64 GB of ram (tested on my server)

Try just compiling on a single core or at most on two. Another solution would be to call the command `m` instead of `make` to let it automatically find optimal settings on your hardware.

Another thing could be that you are missing some packages. Are you sure these packages are installed?

`git-core gnupg flex bison build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z1-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip fontconfig`

They could have different names for your distro (for example if you use Arch).

**Also to note:**

- Compiling should take between 2.5 to 4 hours depending on your cpu performance. - It needs 100GB for downloading the android sources and 100-150GB for compilation.
- You also need at least 12 GB or more to compile on a single core.
- There is [some method](https://www.2net.co.uk/blog/jack-server.html) to compile it on 8GB of RAM by using swap space but this is extremely slow so not recommended.

**My personal hardware and times:**

- Intel xeon e5-2680v3 8 core cpu
- 40 GB ram
- Compile time on make -j1: 2 hours